# When jQuery index() can fail?

Tags: jquery

This is my code :

```
if ($('#fotosingola_6985') instanceof jQuery) {
    console.log($('#fotosingola_6985').attr('id'));
    console.log($('#fotosingola_6985').index(".classObj"));
}
```

well : the output of this code is :

```
fotosingola_6985
-1
```

How can it be possible? jQuery spec says *If a selector string is passed as an argument, .index() returns an integer indicating the position of the original element relative to the elements matched by the selector. If the element is not found, .index() will return -1.*

But the element (yes, it is a jQuery element, I made the control) is found : in fact it returns its id.

Surrounding HTML :

```
<div id="exp-gallery-dettaglio-slideshow-overflowed">    
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="classObj" id="fotosingola_6529">&nbsp;</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="classObj" id="fotosingola_6985">&nbsp;</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="classObj" id="fotosingola_6990">&nbsp;</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="classObj" id="fotosingola_6998">&nbsp;</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="classObj" id="fotosingola_6912">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

**The REAL strange behaviour :**

If I do :

```
console.log($('.classObj').index('#fotosingola_6985'));
```

it return -1. But, if I do :

```
console.log($('.classObj').index($('#fotosingola_6985')));
```

it returns 1, which is correct. How can this be possible?

Comment: Do you mean `$('.classObj').index("#fotosingola_6985")`?

Comment: And how `classObj` comes into the picture exactly?

Comment: It works [just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/RaFR8/) so it means something else is the problem. Can you reproduce this in the fiddle?

Comment: it will be very difficult...is a portlet inside another website...

Comment: Updated the question! Check the last lines... can't believe it :O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your elements are siblings you can code:

```
$('#fotosingola_6985').index();
```

---

`index` accepts a jQuery object or DOM element:

> If .index() is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or jQuery object is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the position of the passed element relative to the original collection.

```
var $elem = $('#fotosingola_6985');
$('.classObj').index($elem)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6sDpx/

Comment: @undefined I'm interested in figuring out *why* -- seems to me like it should work based on the jQuery documentation and common sense.  Any ideas?

Comment: Funny thing : `console.log($('.classObj').index('#fotosingola_6985'));` is -1. `console.log($('.classObj').index($('#fotosingola_6985')));` is 1 (correct). What???

Comment: @undefined in that case his original usage of `.index` in his question works!

Comment: @ExplosionPills There is a difference, `index` disregards it's selector.

Comment: it's a jquery version fail! original use 1.2.0!

Answer (score 0):

I copied-paste your code and shows me `1` instead of `-1`

Somewhere else is the problem.

Use `$('#fotosingola_6985').index()`

[The proof](http://jsfiddle.net/SnakeEyes/NmcDx/)

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is good.

See fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/sP7TJ/1/

What version of jQuery are you using ? And also please try to use :

```
if ($('#fotosingola_6990') instanceof jQuery) {
    console.log($('#fotosingola_6990').attr('id'));
    console.log($('#fotosingola_6990').index(".classObj"));
}
```

and tell me what you recieve. -1 or -2 ?

Comment: Funny thing : `console.log($('.classObj').index('#fotosingola_6985'));` is -1. `console.log($('.classObj').index($('#fotosingola_6985')));` is 1 (correct). What???